# Warning: dbx: module 'mssql' not loaded

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I'm trying connect to MS SQL Server with PHP with DBX. with a phpinf(), i can note that dbx is enabled:

```
dbx

dbx support enabled
dbx version 1.0.0
supported databases MySQL ODBC PostgreSQL Microsoft SQL Server FrontBase Oracle 8 (oci8) Sybase-CT.
```

But when i try connect, appear this error:

```
Warning: dbx: module 'mssql' not loaded.
```

this is the code:

```
dbx_connect("mssql","host","database","user","password");
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: even if it *should* be equivalent : try with DBX_MSSQL instead of 'mssql'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is going to be *not* using DBX.  It's a dead module and should not be used by modern code.

DBX was [**removed from standard PHP** in version 5.1](http://php.net/intro.dbx).  If you have it installed, that means someone went out of their way to install it as a PECL module, or you're using a *very* old PHP version.

On the [requirements page](http://php.net/dbx.requirements), it states:

> To be able to use a database with the dbx-module, the module must be either linked or loaded into PHP

The only module DBX supports for talking to MS SQL Server is the *old* [`mssql_` family](http://php.net/ref.mssql).  That extension is [no longer available in Windows PHP versions 5.3 or later](http://php.net/intro.mssql).

If you're on Linux, and are using an OS-provided PHP release, you might be able to get it installed.  Look for `php-mssql` or `php53-mssql`.  It might also show up when you search package descriptions for "FreeTDS."  If no packages are available, you may be in for a world of pain.  [Getting `mssql_` compiled and installed is quite a bear](http://php.net/mssql.requirements).

However, there are *much* better alternatives.

The goal of DBX was to present a unified set of functions that let you speak to a multitude of the existing PHP database adapters.  That role is now filled by [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo).  If you're on Windows, you should use [PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/ref.pdo-sqlsrv).  If you aren't on Windows, you could use [PDO_DBLIB](http://php.net/ref.pdo-dblib) (which uses the same backend as the `mssql_` family) or [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/ref.pdo-odbc).  If you've never used PDO before, there are a few good [tutorials](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).  That one is targeted at MySQL users, but it still applies to other databases.

If the code you've written is only ever intended to run on MS SQL Server, and you're running PHP on Windows, then you could also consider writing it using the [`sqlsrv_` family of functions](http://php.net/book.sqlsrv) instead.

Comment: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php worked for me on non windows environment.

Comment: @E_p, ah, the details are in the fine print.  It looks like they only discontinued it in *Windows* versions of PHP 5.3+.  I've updated my answer accordingly.